# VLCJ MediaPlayerComponent lagging behind when moving JFrame in Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, vlcj

My code needs to support Windows and Linux using Java 8 (ideally also Mac but I know there is some issue with VLCJ working on Mac if we use newer Java versions). This lagging issue does not happen on Windows but on Linux (I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). I am setting MediaPlayerComponent as contentPane of a JFrame. When I drag the player (which is the JFrame) around, the MediaPlayerComponent part will continue to stay in the old position for another second or so and then snap back into the JFrame. If I drag the player after the video is done playing, the MediaPlayerComponent part will not snap back into the JFrame, and if I move a Window around on my desktop, that window will sit between the JFrame and the MediaPlayerComponent object. 
[MediaPlayerComponent Separated From JFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXG2O.png)
[Web Browser Sandwiches Between MediaPlayerComponet and JFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIEpR.png)
My code:

```
private void setUpPlayer(int x, int y, int width, int height) {     

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            mediaPlayerComponent.release();
            System.exit(0);
        }                           
    });

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    player = mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer();
    frame.add(mediaPlayerComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel controlsPane = new JPanel();
    ...
    frame.add(controlsPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    player.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {...}
    frame.setVisible(true);     
}

public void launchPlayer(int x, int y, int width, int height) {     

    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), getVLCLibPath());
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setUpPlayer(x, y, width, height);
        }
    });     
}

// Can be called to load video again and again
public void loadVideo(String videoPath) {
    player.stop();
    player.prepareMedia(videoPath); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player player = new Player();
    player.launchPlayer(0,0,350,500);
    player.loadVideo("video-path");
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I should just remove the 2 screenshots I took from my question's description.. I used Ubuntu's screenshot app, and when I took a look at my screenshots just now, I noticed the MediaPlayerComponent park (which is supposed to be a pink portrait rectangle) is not even in the screenshots....doesn't seem like the screenshot app was able to capture it..@o@;;

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in my case, it's due to a bug in the Graphic Card's driver. I ran my code on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Intel HD 520 graphics card. Info about the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1537053